# Oracle Apex Calendar Display Column

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I have to make a calendar, which has events, that show workers reason why they are on a vacation, their name and surname. Under the attributes section I can only chose one column. I have seen a code that should join three columns into one and then display them as one event in the calendar. Is there any way I can put more information into the display column section?

Answer (score 2):

> I have seen a code that should join three columns into one

That "code" is called *concatenation*. As you'd concatenate 3 columns, use the double pipe `||` concatenation operator, e.g.

```
select e.first_name||' '|| e.last_name ||' ('|| v.reason ||')' result
from employee e join vacation v on v.empid = e.empid
where ...
```

Comment: Could I implement this code into an existing select? Because I have a statement where I take columns from an existing table, but this column has to be joined.
Lets say:


select
A,
B,
C,
e.first_name||' '|| e.last_name ||' ('|| v.reason ||')' result,
D
from MAIN, empid.

Comment: I believe so, yes.

Comment: Could you please explain this line?
join vacation v on v.empid = v.empid

Comment: it should be e.empid = v.empid, and that is a join

Comment: Right; sorry for the typo, thank you for the comment, @davidm.